# Angular SSR Hot reload not working, no error, hung

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, server-side-rendering

I added angular universal to my project and upon saving, it compiles successfully though in the network tab I can see the request for whatever route im on gets hung on pending and the website stays loading forever in the browser. This issue is not present during CRS. Things I have tried that did not work:

- I have cloned the same project elsewhere to see if it was some fat finger accident
- I have not only add logic to stop DOM methods from being used, I have outright removed the use of them everywhere in the app
- I added 3rd party libraries like Domino js to mock methods on Node
- I started a completely blank angular project, added nothing to it other than angular universal and I get the same issue!

I will try it on another computer soon to see if it is just an issue on this machine.

What could the issue be? I don't get any errors and refreshing the page it works.
Is hot reload broken for me? missing anything?

**EDIT**: I have now tried it on a 2 other Windows machines and the result is the same. Perhaps this is a bug. Essentially makes Angular useless to me.
Angular Version 12.1

Comment: Did you come up with any solution?

Comment: @RossRawlins No. Been busy with other projects. I will update this soon as soon it is working or not. My last attempt is to upgrade to 14, and if that doesnt work downgrade to  a different version. After that though Not much else you can do. Also tried different browsers to no success.

Comment: @RossRawlins Sort of. Provided an answer.

Comment: My suspicion is this is the server portion of universal not terminating the old requests and the rebuild taking a non minimal amount of time. If I watch the build of the nestjs app, the web front end hangs and will stay hung, until I see the routes printed out in the console from the nestjs app. I can then press refresh to get an update. It's a terrible developer experience and I'm not sure who is at fault, universal, nestjs or both. My suspicion is Universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by upgrading my Angular to version 14, and starting a fresh project with SSR added. Frustratingly to say the least but I can finish my project and I copied back in most of my code from the project I was working on.

For what ever reason Angular 11 and 12 were giving me this issue on multiple machines on fresh angular projects. It never gave me any errors to show. I will report back if any time during the rest of the *porting* of code if the issue persists.

Comment: The issue has persisted. Though its completely flaky. Sometimes its there sometimes its not. It could be something to do with the building, maybe it builds twice and causes some issue? I dont know.

Comment: I'm getting this issue too but in Angular 15 Universal.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same hassle when initially integrated the Angular Universal to my project.

After a period of time I consider the according workaround:

- SSR for the single page applications is useful in production for SEO, Open Graph, etc.
- Angular Universal adds additional files:

  - main.server.ts
  - app.server.module.ts
- Then the classic angular approaches are still possible to be used (the old app.module.ts).
- Now for the local development environment I'm continue using the classic "ng serve" command and the Angular continue reloads normally on each file change.
- And the SSR is compileing only for the production build.
- Then if I want to debug something related to the SSR I'm deploying the production build to the test environment and calling the test urls to see the results.

Comment: so for developed as if it were ssr, but built and tested it as client side rendering and would just build ssr for production? I basically did the same thing if you thats what you did. Frustrating I was not able to figure out this issue.

Comment: Yes exactly. SSR only for production environment.